# Excel shorten formula by "naming" a portion of it

Tags: excel

I have the following formula being used throughout a model:

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[s1q6_1 : S1Q6],INDIRECT("table1["&$B$2&"]"),$C$2,INDIRECT("table1["&$B$3&"]"),$C$3,INDIRECT("table1["&$B$4&"]"),$C$4,INDIRECT("table1["&$B$5&"]"),$C$5,INDIRECT("table1["&$B$6&"]"),$C$6,INDIRECT("table1["&$B$7&"]"),$C$7)
```

I have 6 possible filters, that are being represented by these Indirects.

My question is: Is there a way of "Naming" this group of 6 indirects into something such as "Filterprocess", in order to shorten the formula?

This would result in something like: Sumifs(table1[...],"Filterprocess")

Thank you, Evan

Comment: stuff them into hidden cells and then just refer to those cells instead?

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for the response. Could you please give me an example? I haven't entirely followed. Is this the idea of using one indirect for the entire code?